# Can a trigger be forced to run in a separate context than the user in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Let's say I have a SQL Server 2000 table, any name will do, it's irrelevant for this topic.  On this table I have a trigger that runs after update or insert.

The user is able to insert and update the table on which the trigger is attached, but not on other tables that the trigger targets.

If the user modifies data in the original table, I get an exception complaining that the user doesn't have permission to modify data in the target tables of the trigger.

I assume this is caused by the fact that the trigger is running in the context of the user.  Is there a way to have the trigger run in its own context or am I not interpreting the cause of this exception correctly?

**Edit:** I should point out that I'm using SQL Server 2000, so using EXECUTE AS won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers do normally operate with the permissions of the user who made the initial change.  A workaround for something like this is for the trigger to write the data into a temporary table and then have a separate process (logged in as a higher-level user) check for data in the temporary table every so often and move it into the target table.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I guess that would work.  So the separate process would need to be a scheduled job then I guess.  Not really what I was looking for.

Comment: It looks like a trigger is executed by the used that made a change to a table. For auditing purposes, I see in this approach the disadvantage of a temporary table potentially being manipulated by the user being audited. I guess it would be better if Microsoft could have provided a built-in solution for this typical scenario where the user writing to a table needs to be audited from a higher-lvel user that has exclusive access to write to an audit table every time a lower-level user writes to the table being monitored and audited.

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

> EXECUTE AS Specifies the security
>   context under which the trigger is
>   executed. Enables you to control which
>   user account the instance of SQL
>   Server uses to validate permissions on
>   any database objects that are
>   referenced by the trigger.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already come across this document before, I guess I missed the WITH EXECUTE AS feature.  Point of note: The ddart document doesn't even include this information either. http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/create_8.htm

Comment: Also, I notice this is only SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? I was just able to do it without any problems in SQL Server 2005:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Trigger_1
(
    my_string   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Trigger_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_string)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Trigger_2
(
    my_string   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Trigger_2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (my_string)
)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tri_Test_Trigger_1
ON dbo.Test_Trigger_1
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Trigger_2
    (
        my_string
    )
    SELECT
        my_string
    FROM
        INSERTED
END
GO
```

Then I created a login that only had access to Test_Trigger_1, I confirmed that it couldn't access Test_Trigger_2, I inserted a row into Test_Trigger_1 and a row appeared in Test_Trigger_2.

Comment: The trigger is actually crossing out into another database that the user doesn't even have permission to access.  I think this is likely what's causing the problem.  This is helpful though, as it highlights the fact that within the same database at least, it should work.

Comment: Ahh yes, then in that case the EXECUTE AS should do the trick, although I haven't tested it.